# Sort Table by Numbers, which are accompanied by text?

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

All examples I saw were for sorting tables that had columns with only number.

But I want to sort the Price column of this kind of table:

```
 <div id="main-table">
   <div class="wrap">
    <div class="table-wrapper tablesorter">
      <table border="1" class="fixed">
        <col style="width:100px;" />
        <col style="width:100px;" />
        <col style="width:100px;" />
        <col style="width:100px;" />
        <col style="width:100px;" />
        <col style="width:100px;" />
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>h1</th>
            <th>h2</th>
            <th>h3</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>h5</th>
            <th>h6</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>700</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td><span class="price">$75</span></td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>Starting From <span class="price">$100</span></td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>c</td>
            <td>Today Only <span class="price">$50</span></td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>e</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
 </div>  
</div>
```

It may have string like "Starting from", "today only", etc. Only pattern is that the value I will want to sort will always have `$` sign next to it.

If there's no easy way to do this, then I don't mind a workaround solution that will require the clean price value to appear in an additional place, such as `<tr title="75">` or whatever, and then sorting the table by the value inside `title`.

I looked up the tablesorter plugin, and didn't really understand the documentation. I Guess it might be possible with some sort of a text-extraction function, but I don't know how to build one for this case.

[Here's a fiddle with my table and the plugin.](http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/5670/)

(right now I sorted it by the `b` column just to make sure plugin actually works)

Also, how do I get rid of the option which gives the viewer to sort the table by any header he wants to later on? I just need the sorting to occur by default, at loading of the page, and that's it. don't want to let the viewer modify the sorting, but didn't find anything in the documentation as to how to get rid of those arrows that show up inside the headers.

Comment: docs have examples for custom parsers as well as setting sort options

Comment: @charlietfl are [these](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Configuration) the full docs? I don't see for example how can I disable the user from sorting columns by his own will.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own custom parser.  Before you call `tablesorter` add this

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'money', 
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return false; 
    }, 
    format: function(s) { 
      var matches = /\$(\d+)/.exec(s);
      return parseInt(matches ? matches[1] : 0);
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
});
```

Then in the `tablesorter` options, update the `headers` param so that it uses the `money` sorter for column 3 like:

```
 headers: {
    // set "sorter : false" (no quotes) to disable the column
    0: { sorter: false },
    1: { sorter: false },
    2: { sorter: false },
    3: {
        sorter: "money"  // for column 3 use the custom 'money' parser
    },
    4: { sorter: false },
    5: { sorter: false }

},
```

This will use your custom sorter.  I've built the regex there to look for the first entry of $#### (dollar sign followed by digits).  If the format for the number is more complicated, you can adjust the regex.

Comment: Thanks! it works. However, do you have any idea how do I disable the user's option to sort columns by his own will?

Comment: I've updated my answer to disable sorting on all the other columns.  If you want the table to not be sortable at all (except when you render it) you probably don't need this fancy `tablesorter` plugin.

Comment: Thanks. alright then, is there any piece of code which will allow me to get the same results without that plugin? as you said, I don't want it to be sortable at all except on rendering.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to make the page just render data in the right order.  But if you don't own the server or the HTML, then you could try something like they have [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37632/sorting-an-html-table-with-javascript) and instead of binding to `onclick` simply run the sort function on page load.

Comment: I own the html and server, but didn't know it is possible to to sort with PHP as well, if that's what you mean. Is it?

Comment: That is exactly what I mean.  In PHP, you presumably are going through a loop of entries and generating HTML.  You could sort the data there so when the HTML is rendered, it's already in the correct order?  This may change your question to : "How to sort objects in PHP?" ;)

Comment: as far as I understand though this will usually require a database, and currently my table uses both database, but also some static elements, for example, one row can contain a certain word that I chose, and the other won't. I guess that in such case, it will not be possible?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  You should be able to sort this in PHP before you render the data.  My PHP is super rusty so i'm not going to hazard an answer but I'm sure there is a way.  And the sort function would do the same thing as the javascript - rip out the $ and all the non numerics and sort by that value.